# Print List Java with format

Tags: java, arraylist, format

First of all, I have this input:

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666666, -0.3333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 1.3333333333333333], [1.0, 0.0, -0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.0, 3.3333333333333335], [0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, -0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6666666666666667], [0.0, 0.0, -0.3333333333333333, -1.3333333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, -12.666666666666666]];
```

Then I want to output this input formatted. There are some rules:

- Replace `[` for `""`;
- Replace `]` for `"\n"`;
- Replace `,` for `""`; // Remove commas between elements
- Replace `"."` for `","`; // Change dot to comma
- Truncate at the 2nd decimal place; // 1.33333 -> 1.33

So, here's my code for while:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\n");

   sb.append("\n").append(numbersOfExmaple.toString()
           .replaceAll("\\[", "")
           .replaceAll("\\]", "\n")
           .replaceAll(",", "")
           .replaceAll("\\.", ","));
           // String.format isn't working...
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Actually** the output is (note there's a whitespace in the beggining, I want to remove it also):

```
0,0 1,0 0,6666666666666666 -0,3333333333333333 0,0 0,0 1,3333333333333333
 1,0 0,0 -0,3333333333333333 0,6666666666666666 0,0 0,0 3,3333333333333335
 0,0 0,0 -1,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 3,0
 0,0 0,0 -0,6666666666666666 0,3333333333333333 0,0 1,0 0,6666666666666667
 0,0 0,0 -0,3333333333333333 -1,3333333333333333 0,0 0,0 -12,666666666666666
```

**Expected output:**

```
 0,00   1,00   0,67  -0,33   0,00   0,00   1,33 
 1,00   0,00  -0,33   0,67   0,00   0,00   3,33 
 0,00   0,00  -1,00   1,00   1,00   0,00   3,00 
 0,00   0,00  -0,67   0,33   0,00   1,00   0,67 
 0,00   0,00  -0,33  -1,33   0,00   0,00  -12,67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
private static String matrixString(Double[][] numbersOfExmaple) {
    StringBuilder answ = new StringBuilder();

    for (Double[] arr : numbersOfExmaple) {
        for (Double val : arr) {
            answ.append(String.format("%7.2f", val).replace('.', ','));
        }
        answ.append('\n');
    }

    return answ.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 You can parse the string to array 
2 truncate decimal
3 print your array elements 1 by 1 ,before print replace . By ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of method

```
for(ArrayList<Double> tmp:ad){
      for(Double t:tmp)
            System.out.print(String.format("%.2f ",t).replace(".",","));
      System.out.println();
}
```

Here `ad` id the arraylist of arraylist add `tmp` is `ArrayList<Double>`